# Action attribute set to a string

Tags: html, string, jsp, action

What does it mean to set an action attribute to a string. e.g

```
    <form method = "POST" action = "doDropClass">
```

I understand that if action = "loginAuthenticate.jsp" meaning that the request and the data will be send to a server side application ---loginAuthenticate.jsp
But what does it mean to assign a string to action attribute like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

The **action** attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.

You can write `action = "loginAuthenticate.jsp"` for a jsp file.
For a servlet `action = "doDropClass"` there needs to be the url-pattern mapped with the servlet.

a JSP directly resolves into a URL pattern, whereas servlet needs url-pattern match for url resolution.

When you use a String to action attribute like `action = "doDropClass"` the servlet container will search the corresponding url-pattern in web.xml to create a valid url pattern that will call the servlet `com.stack.DoDropClass` for the below example.
**Web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>doDropClass</servlet-name>
  <servlet-path>com.stack.DoDropClass</servlet-path>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>doDropClass</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/doDropClass</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean to set an action attribute to a string

You can't set it to anything other than a string. So it means what it usually means: When the form is submitted, send the data to the URL in the action attribute.

> I understand that if action = "loginAuthenticate.jsp" meaning that the request and the data will be send to a server side application ---loginAuthenticate.jsp But what does it mean to assign a string to action attribute like the example above.

The same thing. It just means the URL doesn't have `.jsp` in it. There is no such thing as a file extension in a URL. Things that look like file extensions are usually just a legacy of generating a URL by mapping it onto directly onto a server's file system.

There are plenty of other ways to resolve URLs. Common ones include using:

- a rewriting system (such as Apache HTTPD's mod_rewrite) to use regular expressions to map URLs onto files
- handling all URL resolution inside a server side application (e.g. using a MVC design pattern) instead of leaving it up to the web server.